# Divs show() at different times, but related CSS animations all run with same timeline. Works with Chrome and IE, not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, css-animations

Trying to get multiple divs floating up, like an infinite balloon effect.

Divs appear every few seconds and their related CSS animation is supposed to start at the beginning of its timeline. I got it working in Chrome v34 and IE v10, but Firefox v29 has all the CSS animations running on the same timeline (so new divs start mid animation).

Rather hard to explain, so check out the example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/miguo

Note: All the divs are using the same class and animation class, so I tried giving each div a unique id with a unique animation, but still had the same error.

Thanks a lot, going crazy with deadline, and I'm supposed to be on vacation :P

Comment: The best way to do this is to assign each one a unique queue http://api.jquery.com/queue/ Right now all of your animations are in one queue (the default) and are therefore affected by each other rather than being independent of one another.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm reading up on .queue, and finding quite complex examples, and having trouble integrating that into my already complex animation. Could you share some words of wisdom on where to plug that into my example?

Comment: It may require a re-thinking of your logic @J3ff since you're using CSS to accomplish the actual animation. IIRC CSS doesn't have the concept of queuing animations.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: start the animation via adding a new class to the element.

```
 $(divs).addClass('floating-animation');
```

Here is an updated version http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tIhDq

Tested on Chrome v34, IE v10, and Firefox v29